# How to download new files from server using Netbeans' FTP client

Tags: netbeans, ftp

I cannot download or synchronize files that reside on the server to the dev computer running Netbeans 7.4. However, uploading is not a problem. This is a problem when i need to work remotely from another machine (laptop).

On the server, all permissions and files permissions are set to the name listed in the Netbeans FTP client. So again, I am able to upload files, just not see any existing files that are available for download from the server.

Any help please?? Should I switch IDEs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server that I am using is a Mac (OSx mountain lion) server.

On the developer machine running Netbeans, follow ProjectName >> Properties >> Run Configuration >> Remote Configuration (manage button). Here WHOLE directory string is required under Initial Directory:

/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/

not simply the directory string from which the FTP server places you, for example my FTP server takes me directly here:

{ftp}/Default/

My sFTP settings now work:
Initial Directory: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/